# Is there a way to see the state of the Xbox button using Xinput.h? (Using an Xbox One controller)

Tags: c++, xinput

Basically the title. I'm using Xinput.h on Windows with an Xbox One controller to control the mouse and a bunch of other common key presses remotely, and I really want to use the Xbox button to enable/disable the controller. The Xinput.h documentation for the wButtons variable in the Gamepad struct [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/XInput/ns-xinput-xinput_gamepad) doesn't have a way to read the state of the Xbox button, so is there another way to read it?

Do I need another library, separate from Xinput.h, to manage this?

Comment: That button is known as the "guide" button, and as far as I know it's not exposed by XInput itself. You might be able to handle it using raw input.